# Rsync transfer-log on server site?

Tags: backup, rsync

I have a backup script that copies contents of user directories on local workstations using rsync to another server. I need to use ssh for that because I don't want to run a rsyncd on the backup system.

I want to have an email that tells me, if the backup from the user workstations went well but I don't want to get emails from all user workstations frequently.

I have a cronjob for the emails set up that already sends me server status reports frequently (including sshd logs). But is it possible to get some kind of logging on the server site when rsync runs over ssh? Best would be, if I get only the part where it tells me how many bytes where transferred and/or if the connection did break before the transfer finished.

Edit: I might want to add, that the backup system is a NAS based on NAS4Free. I didn't mention it at first because I just now learned that this matters as the syslogd is quirky to configure additional sockets within a chroot.

Comment: Not sure.  The option I have used is to use LFTP+SFTP and achieve the same results, but faster.  LFTP can use SFTP and has a `mirror` subsystem that can spawn as many threads as you wish and has nearly all the same capabilities as rsync.  SFTP on the server side can be set to `VERBOSE` logging and that will give you what files were transfered and what commands were run.  Added security bonus, you can chroot so your backup job doesn't have a shell, if you so desire.

Comment: Thanks I will have a look into LFTP. Unfortunately rsync over sftp doesn't work, because it needs to execute rsync on the remote site and thus needs ssh with execution permissions. Maybe LFTP would do what I need.

Comment: Exactly.  That was the exact problem I ran in to and what led me to use LFTP.

Comment: Check the rsync manpage for "USING RSYNC-DAEMON FEATURES VIA A REMOTE-SHELL CONNECTION".

Comment: I read that but how is that supposed to help me with my issue?

Comment: @Aaron I tried to run it in a chroot but then my logging doesn't work. I can create `dev/log` sockets in each directory but that would mean, I'd have to specify each socket for each user in the command line that starts syslogd. rsyslog has a command file option for these sockets but not syslogd if I understood that correctly.

Comment: That is correct.  If you have configuration management, you can create one log device and `/etc/rsyslog.d/logging_user.conf` per account that needs this level of logging.  Future releases of RHEL/CentOS will preclude this need, but for now, that device is required if you chroot.

Comment: Unfortunately I am using a NAS based on BSD that has syslogd and not rsyslog it's also an embedded system that makes compiling and installing additional packages awkward. For syslogd, I could only find the command line option -l /pathtochroot/ to add additional sockets but not a config file option like rsyslog has. Maybe I am just stuck here. Thanks for your help anyhow.